# Javascript Raphael problems with function in loop

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, raphael

Please bear with me, I'm still new to Javascript...

Here are two fiddles. The only difference between them is one has a text object as a title and the other does not; but this difference profoundly affects what happens when I mouseover the circle objects.

What I want is the behavior of the second fiddle, when there is a title like the first fiddle.

I've been trying to figure out how to get my function out of the loop so JSHint stops giving me an error... I have a feeling this behavior is caused by my lack of understanding of closure, binding, etc.

[Fiddle 1 with title, mouseover is weird](http://jsfiddle.net/considerphlebas/pn2V7/4/)

[Fiddle 2 no title, mouseover works](http://jsfiddle.net/considerphlebas/6Njgs/3/)

```
//Code for Fiddle 1: the only difference in Fiddle 2 is the indicated portion is commented out

var rsr = Raphael("holder", '1160', '1400');

// in the next fiddle this will be commented out
rsr.text(220, 50, 'Title').attr({
    'font-size': 32,
    'text-anchor': 'middle'
});
// end of comment out in Fiddle 2

var cir = []; // an array of circles
var xco = [206, 144.9, 317.4, 317.5]; // x coordinates of circle centers
var yco = [167.7, 231.8, 191.4, 256.8]; // y coordinates of circle centers
var rd = [25.5, 46, 34, 18.5]; // radii of circles
var circcolr = ['#939dac', '#000000', '#ecea5a', '#0da9f2']; // fill colors of circles
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) { // loop to draw circles
    cir[i] = rsr.circle(xco[i], yco[i], rd[i]);
    cir[i].attr({
        fill: circcolr[i],
            'fill-opacity': 1,
        stroke: 'none'
    });
}

for (var i in cir) {
    (function (st) {
        console.log(st.id);
        st.node.onmouseover = function () {
            st.animate({
                r: rd[st.id] * 1.2
            }, 200);
        };
        st.node.onmouseout = function () {
            st.animate({
                r: rd[st.id]
            }, 100);
        };
    })(cir[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty much there in the console logging you're already doing.

- In the first case you create 5 objects the title and 4 circles so the title has id = 0 and the circles have id = 1, 2, 3, and 4.
- In the second case you're only creating the circles so they have id = 0, 1, 2, 3

When you index into the rd array you're off by one in the title case. Changing the code at the end to this makes it work the same...

```
for (var i in cir) {
    (function (cir, i) {
        console.log(cir[i]);
        cir[i].node.onmouseover = function () {
            cir[i].animate({
                r: rd[i] * 1.2
            }, 200);
        };
        cir[i].node.onmouseout = function () {
            cir[i].animate({
                r: rd[i]
            }, 100);
        };
    })(cir, i);
}
```

Comment: Off by one error, I'm so embarrassed... new as I am to javascript, I was confusing the ID number of the object with the index number of the array. Thanks for your help.